# dtd restrictions

Tags: xml, dtd

I am making a xml for a survey taken by students in a class. My dtd of responses looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE responses [
<!ELEMENT responses (student)+>
<!ELEMENT student (response?)>
]>
```

This model requires at least one student which will either have or not have a response.

Is there a way to require at least one student who has a response?

Answer (score 0):

Not in DTDs, no.  You could of course make response a required child of student.